# ¿Como crear una ventana emergente en Unity?

Tags: unity

Estoy haciendo un juego, y necesito que al final aparezca una ventana emergente, como las que aparecen en c# cuando se usa:

```
MessageBox.Show("Haz ganado");
```

[image: Una ventana como esta, que sea externa al juego]

Una ventana como la de arriba, que sea externa al juego (una ventana aparte de la del juego). Pero cuando uso el código de arriba en Unity, no lo reconoce.
Como creo ventanas emergentes?

Comment: Probaste un bloque de código C# en unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity usa DisplayDialog [(documentación)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.DisplayDialog.html).

Ejemplo:

```
EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Título del mensaje",
                "¿Desea hacer esta acción?", "Sí", "Nop")
```

El método retorna un booleano, `true` si el usuario hace clic en OK, `false` en cualquier otro caso.